# Why does kubebuilder include // +build !ignore_autogenerated in zz_generated.deepcopy.go files?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubebuilder

Every deepcopy generated file that is produced by `make` with kubebuilder produces a file with a `// +build !ignore_autogenerated` build tag directive at the top.

```
//go:build !ignore_autogenerated
// +build !ignore_autogenerated

/*
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

// Code generated by controller-gen. DO NOT EDIT.
```

Why is this specific build tag directive added to these generated files? What's its purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used by `controller-gen` to identify files it generated, it will only overwrite those.

E.g. edit a generated `zz_generated.deepcopy.go` and run `make generate` => the file is overwritten.

Now edit the file again, also remove the two lines with the build constraints (the `go:build` line is for go >= 1.17, the `+build`line for older versions IIRC) and run `make generate` again => your changes to the file have not been overwritten this time.

Comment: Interesting. Why does it not just use the file name to know which files that is has generated?

Comment: Well, it's not just `zz_generated.deepcopy.go`.  And this way it can also detect renamed files.